# How do I copy key bindings from VS configs to another PC?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My PC died and I can' boot it, however I've copied profile files. How can I extract VS settings (particularly key bindings) and import them to a new installation?

Comment: Tools + Export/Import, Import, select the .vssettings file you recovered.  Untick everything except the Options/Environment/Keyboard

Comment: @Hans Passant, under <profile>\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings - that's it.

Comment: @Hans Passant, why don't make this an answer?

Comment: Did it work?  Then you ought to make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this was to use VS settings import wizard on a "\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings" file recovered from the died PC.